# Reference to class property is null

Tags: javascript

I was under the impression that anything that is part of an object is set by reference. This doesn't seem to be the case in this example

```
class System {}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.system = null;
    this.dictionary = {
      system: this.system
    }
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.system = new System();
  }
}

var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar.system); // System{}
console.log(bar.dictionary.system); // null
```

I would expect that `dictionary` is holding a reference to `this.system` which starts as `null`, but only because what it is referencing is `null`. However as can be seen, `bar.dictionary.system` is actually still null even though its reference was updated.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: You are assigning `this.system` after you call the base constructor. If you do this, you don't update dictionary once you call `this.System = new System();

Comment: @Cubemaster Why is the dictionary not updated, if it is holding on to the reference of `this.system`? If objects are passed by reference, it should update.. It's like a pointer - at first it points to null, but now it should be pointing to `System`

Comment: I am not the best person to be offering advice, because I haven't written a word of javascript in my life. However, if it is similar to any other OO language I know, the value of the dictionary is still what it was when you first set it. I don't know all the fancy coding terminology, but it seems that dictionary is not referencing the system dynamically, it will only update if you force it to

Comment: @EKW Phrased it better than I can, but see my modified answer for a similar example that should make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's still being set by reference. The issue here is that by writing `this.system = new System()` you're not modifying the referenced value, you're making `this.system` reference a different value altogether. Meanwhile, `this.dictionary.system` is still pointing towards the old value.

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.system = {};
        this.dictionary = { system: this.system };
    }
}
class Bar {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.system.bananas = 5;
    }
}
```

this would correctly add bananas to `this.system` and `this.dictionary.system`, as you're modifying the value being referenced, not making `this.system` reference a different value entirely.

Comment: I see.. so it's not like a pointer then, where it's still going to point to the same address regardless of the contents

Comment: @ICU_ yes, exactly! It's exactly like a pointer. If my answer helped, please do remember to mark it as correct :)

Comment: You just said the exact opposite thing from each other. OP said it is NOT like a pointer, and you said it IS like a pointer.. Which one is it?

Comment: @Cubemaster whoops, I misread. It *is* like a pointer in the sense that if you change the pointer's address, it's no longer pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Ah, got it. I was incredibly confused for a minute there.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `this.system` after you call the base constructor. If you do this, you don't update dictionary once you call `this.system = new System();`

Here is a rough imitation of what the compiler sees:

```
this.system = null;
this.dictionary = {
  system: this.system
}
this.system = new System();
```

See how you are not actually updating `this.dictionary`.

Imagine I have this code:

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
a = 6;
```

At this point, `a` is 6 and `b` is 5. This is because I set `b` to the previous value of `a`. If I want to update `b`, I have to equate them again.

Comment: This is understandable though, because only objects are passed by reference.

Comment: a and b are both objects, don't forget. they are objects of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a value of system, which is assigned, after you actually want to use it. That's like the follwing, which won't also work

```
var x = null;
console.log(x);
x = "Hallo Welt";
```

The problem in your case is, you couldn't simply swap the call of `super()` with the assignment - which would solve the problem. Instead you could use properties or functions, which are getting overridden in the child class and return the actual value.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.dictionary = {
      system: this.system
    }
  }

  get system() { return null; }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  get system() {
    return this._system ?
      this._system :
      this._system = new System();
  }
}
```